# De Morgan's Law optimization with overloaded operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, compiler-optimization

Every programmer should know that:

```cpp
!(p || q)  <=>  !p && !q
!(p && q)  <=>  !p || !q
```

([De Morgan's Laws)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Under some circumstances, in order to optimize the program, it may happen that compiler modifies `!p && !q` to `!(p || q)`.

The two expressions are equivalent, and it makes no difference evaluating the first or the second.
But in C++ it is possible to overload operators, and the overloaded operator may not always respect this property. So transforming the code this way will actually modify the code.

Should the compiler use De Morgan's Laws when `!`, `||` and `&&` are overloaded?

Comment: Any sane compiler writer avoids trusting that the programmer has correctly implemented the inverse operator.  Not doing so is a very common bug.

Comment: In general the compiler can only apply such transformations to your program if they do not change the observable behavior (side effects, output) of your program. When `p` and `q` are boolean primitives, De Morgan's laws can be applied, sure, since that won't change the observable behavior. When `p` and `q` have overloaded operators this may or may not be true. The C++ standard says nothing about De Morgan's laws; compilers are only "allowed" to make use of it by virtue of knowing that it won't change behaviour.

Comment: If I went around my office of 15 programmers and asked any of them to name a single De Morgan's law, they would not be able to do so. So the statement "every programmer should know" is a little misleading...

Comment: Note that C++ requires short-circuit behavior from `&&` and `||`. De Morgan's Laws do not consider this. Doesn't matter in this specific case, though.

Comment: @corsiKa: "should" and "will" are two very different words

Comment: @corsiKa: So your coworkers don't know the *names* of these laws, which is a very different issue from knowing the laws themselves.

Comment: @BenVoigt I would not consider the knowledge of the laws to be common, no. Simply put, it's not used very often. Generally such statements are overly verbose to make it clear what they're doing in terms of business logic and the JIT takes care of the rest.

Comment: @corsiKa: Every C++ programmer should be able, given code `if (p || q) { f(); } else { g(); }` be able to answer "Under what conditions is `g()` called?"  Some may say "when `(p || q)` is false", but most can apply DeMorgan's Theorem and know that "`f()` is called if either p or q is true, `g()` when p and q are both false"  That's knowing the laws, even if they don't call them by name.

Comment: I feel that's disingenuous to my point. Most developers I know simply don't care about expressing in a different way something they can already express clearly. If pressed long enough they would surely be able to work them out (with your example being the easiest, perhaps even for a nonprogrammer) but most devs just... don't... care...

Comment: @HansPassant If that principle was applied consistently throughout the language design, there would be no such thing as undefined behavior. But in a language where there are constructions with undefined behavior, the compiler is already trusting that the programmer doesn't do something silly that invokes undefined behavior. The standard could have said that overloads that do not comply with boolean algebra yields undefined behavior.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Note that:

> **Builtin operators && and || perform short-circuit evaluation** (do not evaluate the second operand if the result is known after evaluating the first), but **overloaded operators behave like regular function calls** and **always evaluate both operands**.
>
> ...
>   Because the short-circuiting properties of operator&& and operator|| do not apply to overloads, and because types with boolean semantics are uncommon, only two standard library classes overload these operators ...
>
> Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical
>   (emphasis mine)

And that:

> If there is a user-written candidate with the same name
>   and parameter types as a built-in candidate operator function, the **built-in operator function is hidden** and
>   is not included in the set of candidate functions.
>
> Source: n4431 13.6 Built-in operators [over.built] (emphasis mine)

To summarize: overloaded operators behave like regular, user-written functions.

NO, the compiler will not replace a call of a user-written function with a call of another user-written function.
Doing otherwise would potentially violate the ["as if"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) rule.

Answer (score 18):

I think that you have answered your own question: no, a compiler can not do this. Not only the operators can be overloaded, some can not be even defined. For example, you can have `operator &&` and `operator !` defined, and `operator ||` not defined at all.

Note that there are many other laws that the compiler can not follow. For example, it can not change `p||q` to `q||p`, as well as `x+y` to `y+x`.

(All of the above applies to overloaded operators, as this is what the question asks for.)

Comment: If you are talking about not overloaded, the compiler can change p||q to q||p if it can prove that q has no side effects or undefined behaviour if p is false, and p has no side effects if q is false. So if (x >= 0 && x <= 100) can be swapped, but if (p != NULL && *p == 1) can't.

Comment: @gnasher729, updated the answer to show that this is about overloaded operators, as that is what question asks for.

Comment: @gnasher729 what you're talking about is the result of the allowance in the spec that implementations must "emulate only the observable behavior". Sure, it can re-arrange 'q || p' if it can prove that the result (including side effects) is exactly equivalent, but given that the result _is_ then exactly equivalent, this re-arrangement has no observable effect. The question OP asks is, I think, specifically asking about re-arrangement which _does_ change the observable behavior.

Answer (score 9):

No, in that case the transformation would be invalid. The permission to transform `!p && !q` into `!(p || q)` is implicit, by the as-if rule. The as-if rule allows any transformation that, roughly speaking, cannot be observed by a correct program. When overloaded operators are used and would detect the transformation, that automatically means the transformation is no longer allowed.

Comment: Unless the compiler has analysed the overloaded operators and determined that the as-if rule still applies. Unlikely that a compiler even tries :-)

Comment: @gnasher729: The compiler will analyze the overloaded operators, but not for the purpose of this transformation.  After inlining, it might find that there are opportunities to transform operations on built-in types, and redundant code folding might then cause it to reuse the branch implemented in the complementary operator.... but none of this is an explicit attempt to apply DeMorgan's Theorem to user-defined operators.

Comment: @BenVoigt Actually, when I read that comment, I thought it seemed like an interesting heuristic that a future compiler could legitimately try even if current compilers don't: see if optimisation opportunities arise if such transformation are performed, and if so, then check if the operators are implemented in a way that allows that transformation. For some very specific programs, it could be very useful, and if it doesn't harm the overall performance of the compiler noticeably, then that might be reason enough to keep it like that. (I do think it's unlikely too, but I like it nonetheless.)

Answer (score 5):

**Overloaded operators *per se* are just syntactic sugar for function calls**; the compiler itself is not allowed to make any assumption about the properties that may or may not hold for such calls. Optimizations that exploit properties of some specific operator (say, De Morgan's for boolean operators, commutativity for sums, distributivity for sum/product, transformation of integral division in an appropriate multiplication, ...) can be employed only when the "real operators" are used.

Notice instead that some parts of the *standard library* may associate some specific semantic meaning to overloaded operators - for example, `std::sort` by default expects an `operator<` that complies to a strict weak ordering between the elements - but this is of course listed in the prerequisites of each algorithm/container.

(incidentally, overloading `&&` and `||` should probably be avoided anyway since they lose their short-circuiting properties when overloaded, so their behavior becomes surprising and thus potentially dangerous)

Answer (score 4):

You are asking whether the compiler can arbitrarily rewrite your program to do something you did not write it to do.

The answer is: *of course not!*

- Where De Morgan's laws apply, they may be applied.
- Where they don't, they may not.

It's really that simple.

Comment: "You are asking whether the compiler can arbitrarily rewrite your program to do something you did not write it to do" - no,  OP is asking whether the compiler can apply a specific transform in specific cases.

Comment: @davmac Right, and this specific transformation would be an arbitrary rewriting of the program to do something the OP did not write it to do.

Comment: No, it would be a _specific_ (not arbitrary) transformation ("rewriting") of the program in a specific case. OP is asking whether the language allows the compiler to perform this transformation. That is different from asking whether the compiler can make any arbitrary change to the program. Also it being something "the OP did not write it to do" is dependent on the actual rules of the language. The C++ standard might have allowed such a transformation; as it happens, it does not - which is what the OP is asking. The answer is only obvious if you already know it.

Comment: In particular, it would be possible, and maybe even reasonable, for the C++ spec to require that those operators, when overloaded, must be written in such a way as to respect De Morgan's Laws. As it happens, the spec does not require this (which leaves open the possibility to use those operators for other things than logical conjunction, disjunction and negation, e.g. in a parser combinator DSL or something like that), and so the optimization is invalid.

Comment: @davmac: Well, if you will insist on continuing to misread the answer, then indeed you will find it lacking.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Yes, of course it is possible for C++ to be a language that is not C++. But, it turns out, it is not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit IMO the OP's question is markedly different from your re-statement of it, and the implied obviousness of the answer is valid only for the re-stated version (which differs semantically). Perhaps you misread or misinterpreted the question, rather than (or as well as) it being me misreading your answer.

Comment: @davmac: Nope, I neither misread nor misinterpreted the question. Rather, you are misunderstanding the mode of my usage of the word "arbitrary". Don't worry about it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "arbitrary" isn't a verb and thus has no mode. I don't understand what you mean by "mode of my usage". But I'm not worried about it, I assure you. If you don't want to discuss any further that's fine, though I'd suggest that if there's confusion about what your answer means that you can always try to express it in less ambiguous or more explicit ways.

Comment: @davmac: No need; you're clearly nitpicking and obviously understand what my answer says.

Comment: Just like C++ has a specific rule that allows the compiler to elide copies in certain scenarios, even if that could change the behaviour of the program when the copy operation is user defined, it could have a specific rule that allows the compiler to apply certain specific transformations like De Morgan's law or replacing `x != y` with `!(x == y)`. It does not have such a rule, but that's not obvious.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not nitpicking and accusing me of this and of wilfully misreading your answer is not constructive. You use "of course not!" in your answer as if it is fundamentally obvious, but by my understanding of the question this is not the case (as others have also noted), unless you already know the C++ language reasonably well. OP presumably doesn't and there's no need to be disparaging in your answer.

Comment: @davmac: Let's move on. I dispute your findings and your accusation, and am happy with the answer as is. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Copy elision is indeed a good example of compiler modifying the program to do something else than could be intended. Thus, this answer indeed seems misleading (as it suggests that such scenarios are impossible).

Comment: @BartoszKP: No, it says the compiler cannot rewrite the OP's program. I didn't say any program ever in the history of man.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't mean that you explicitly state that. But the "of course not" part of your answer can be understood this way.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly.

If p and q are expressions so that p does not have overloaded operators, short circuit evaluation is in effect: expression q is going to be evaluated only if p is false.

If p is of non-primitive type, there is no short circuit evaluation and overloaded function could be anything - even not related to the conventional usage.

Compiler will do its optimizations in its own way. Perhaps it might result de Morgan identities, but not on the level of if condition replacement.

Answer (score 3):

DeMorgan's laws apply to the **semantics** of those operators. Overloading applies to the **syntax** of those operators. There is no guarantee that an overloaded operator implements the semantics that are needed for DeMorgan's laws to apply.

Comment: "There is no guarantee that an overloaded operator implements the semantics that are needed for DeMorgan's laws to apply" - OP acknowledges this in the question. I think you mis-understand what OP is trying to ask.

Comment: @davmac - I think you misunderstood my answer.

Comment: I guess it's possible - care to elaborate? OP pretty clearly recognizes that overloaded operators might not implement the semantics that are need for DeMorgan's identities to apply. I believe that OP is asking whether the compiler is allowed to transform expressions according to those identities regardless of overloading and whether the identity actually holds (which is admittedly an interpretation, not the literal meaning of the question as asked). Your answer doesn't seem to address that. Are you just addressing the literal question, then?

Answer (score 1):

> But in C++ it is possible to overload operators,  and the overloaded operator may not always respect this property.

Overloaded operator is no longer an operator, it is a function call.

```
class Boolean
{
  bool value;

  ..

  Boolean operator||(const Boolean& b)
  {
      Boolean c;
      c.value = this->value || b.value;
      return c;
  }

  Boolean logical_or(const Boolean& b)
  {
      Boolean c;
      c.value = this->value || b.value;
      return c;
  }
}
```

So this line of code

```
Boolean a (true);
Boolean b (false);

Boolean c = a || b;
```

is equivalent to this

```
Boolean c = a.logical_or(b);
```